# How handle non-numeric values while calculating in PHP

Tags: php

I used this example piece of code to calculate numbers. How to handle if non-numeric value is entered?

```
function calculateSum($numbers) {

    $sum = 0;

    foreach ($numbers as $number) {

        $sum += $number;

    }

    return $sum;

}

$numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

$result = calculateSum($numbers);

echo "The sum of the numbers is: $result";
```

I was expecting a way to handle the non-numeric values.